# quick accessing to element of std::map

Tags: c++, stl

Do you know if it is any difference in performance when I access a `std::map` element using `find` or `operator []`?

One returns an `iterator` and the other a `const ref` to the object.

Which one might be quicker becuase of all of the behind the scene of the STL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use [] on a key that doesn't exist, the default element will be inserted. This default element depends on your map definition (for example, for an int it will be a zero).

When you use find, there is no "automatic" insertion, so it can be quite faster if you often search for keys that does not exist.

Comment: I would add that operator[] basically call find. If the element does not exist, it uses the position where the element should have been to add it. It "just" cost en element construction.

Comment: Good point. Just comparing speed between two things that doesn't do the same thing tend to be misleading.

Answer (score -3):

`find()` is O(n). `operator []` is O(1). Therefore the latter is (usually) faster.

Comment: It depends on your map implementation.
Requirements for std::map is O(log(n)) for find (and operator [] uses more or less find).

Comment: You must be confused between hashmaps and maps.